# Showing a polynomial differential equation is homogeneous and non-linear

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on an assignment and am unsure where to head with this problem. I need to show that the following differential equation is homogeneous and non-linear, given $ y = y(t) = dx/dt $ and $x = x(t)$

$$
f(x,y)=2x^3 + 2x^2 y + 5xy^2 + 2y^3 
$$

Does anyone have any hints on where to even begin? I'm quite confused...

Cheers

Comment: I think the last term must be $2y^3$. Am i right? and for the hint part: function $f(z): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is homogeneous if $f(az) = a^kf(z)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function  . Also notice $z$ is a vector i.e. $z = (z_1 , z_2 , ... , z_n)$ so we have $az = (az_1 , az_2 , ... , az_n)$. Also definition of linear function is: $f(ax+by) = af(x) + bf(y)$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Ahh of course. A bit of mistype, I apologise. Also, thank you for the hint!